# Can I redirect to other subdirectory of another site with CloudFlare

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, cloudflare

I use CloudFlare as DNS and want to point one of my site say productA.com to my main site my-main-site.com/productA. Is this possible with CloudFlare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a page rule...  Cloudflare documents this quite fully:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-

Now, granted, you'll need to have cloudflare's acceleration enabled for the domain(s) you want to redirect. (HTTP redirections do NOT happen at the DNS level.. they happen via HTTP therefore you NEED cloudflare to be proxying the HTTP for this to work...)  In order for that to happen, add an A record pointing to a webserver you control, and make sure cloudflare CDN is enabled on that record.

Comment: Yes, I have read that, but what `A record` and `CName www` I need to point to? I leave it blank and got `No A, AAAA or CNAME record found pointing to my-domain.com — root domain will not resolve.` which seem to make page rule broke.

Comment: I updated my answer with the info you need...

Comment: Thanks it work right now, I just point A record to my unused IP and page rule start working.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it is working. : )

Comment: So in this case request would never reach my server right? because CloudFlare redirect all of them according to Page Rule.

Comment: Exactly. The only reason you need to put in any A record at all is so to make Cloudflare active for that name.  Do make sure to put an A record for www as well, if you want that redirected...