# How to run Ghost and PrestaShop on the same domain, when hosted on different providers?

Tags: ghost

I would like to host:

- A [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) website on https://www.example.com
- A [PrestaShop](https://www.prestashop.com/en) site on https://www.example.com/shop

They will be hosted on 2 different providers.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) can only be pointed at a single provider using DNS.

You could have one provider forward on calls for a subpath to the other provider.

Or you could introduce a third piece to the puzzle. If the one provider is something like Cloudflare, that could then pass traffic for the subpath to one PrestaShop, and the rest to Ghost

Comment: Some more info: It won't work of the site you are trying to proxy to is on a shared instance (no unique IP address). https://www.networkchimp.fun/tutorials/portzilla-location.html looks like it will be an easy solution. Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/663966/can-i-redirect-to-other-subdirectory-of-another-site-with-cloudflare and https://statushero.com/blog/serving-a-blog-from-a-subdirectory-with-cloudflare-workers/